mongoimport getting error trying to import json file witn date field
I have created collection "mycollection"  with the following mongoschema
db.createCollection("testing",{
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: ["date"],
            properties: {
                date: {
                    bsonType: "date",
                    description: "must be a date and is required"
                }
            }
        }
    } })

I want to use mongoimport to import the below json file "datefile.json" into the collection above that I have created
[
    {
      "date": "2024-04-07T12:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "date": "2024-04-08T10:30:00Z"
    },
    {
      "date": "2024-04-09T08:45:00Z"
    }
  ]

However, I am getting this error
"2024-04-07T14:30:57.453-0400    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2024-04-07T14:30:57.459-0400    continuing through error: Document failed validation
2024-04-07T14:30:57.459-0400    continuing through error: Document failed validation
2024-04-07T14:30:57.459-0400    continuing through error: Document failed validation
2024-04-07T14:30:57.460-0400    0 document(s) imported successfully. 3 document(s) failed to import." 

when I type the below command
mongoimport --db mydatabase--collection mycollection --file datefile.json --jsonArray.
My question is how do I create the json file for the created schema above

I found a solution. The json should be like this one below: -
[
    {
      "date": { "$date": "2024-04-07T12:00:00Z" }
    },
    {
      "date": { "$date": "2024-04-08T10:30:00Z" }
    },
    {
       "date": { "$date": "2024-04-09T08:45:00Z" }
    }
  ]

